# Use firebase timestamp within a string

Tags: firebase

Given I have the following data structure:

```
{
  operation: {
    abc123: {
      action: "sendEmail",
      status: "pending:167423383473"
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to insert an operation with a status of the following form?

```
"pending:Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP"
```

Edit: The reason they need to be in the same column is that I need to sort the operations by status and timestamp. With firebase this is only possible if they're combined into a single property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is not possible, since `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is actually a placeholder object, `{.sv: "timestamp"}`, until it reaches the server. Concatenating it with a string would not have the desired effect. I would suggest the following solution:

```
{
  operation: {
    abc123: {
      action: "sendEmail",
      status: {
        type: "pending",
        timestamp: 167423383473
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or possibly:

```
{
  operation: {
    abc123: {
      action: "sendEmail",
      statustype: "pending",
      statustimestamp: 167423383473
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to order the operations by status and timestamp. Unfortunately it's only possible to do this on a single property with firebase. You can work around this by putting both the status and timestamp in a single property but then I arrive at the problem of not being able to use the firebase timestamp.

Comment: If you pass a completion callback, you can read back the value the server used and then set the secondary property based on that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355200/future-timestamp-as-key-in-firebase/22416101#22416101

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen I hadn't noticed that transaction returned a snapshot on complete, very useful to know!

Comment: Note that you should not use transaction() and set() on the same data tree. This is going to create nondeterministic results. You'll want to do one or the other but not both.

Comment: @kato thanks for putting that out, it does make sense that using the two together would cause unexpected results.